# How to allow multiple item selection (checkboxes) when using server side filtering and pagination through RXJS Subject

Tags: angular

I need to request data from my REST api, using Angular 4.3 HttpClient. My component uses `Subject` class to provide server side filtering (as the user types the term) and pagination, but I also need to allow multiple selection of items using the checkboxes in the results data grid.

I have the following code to create a data grid:

```
<tr *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles$ | async">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle-selection" id="vehicle-{{vehicle.id}}" value="{{vehicle.id}}" [ngModel]="vehicle.checked" (ngModelChange)="setChecked(vehicle.id, $event)" /></td>
    <td>{{vehicle.chassis}}</td>
    <td>{{vehicle.lastUpdate || '' | amFromUtc | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}}</td>
    <td>{{vehicle.description}}</td>
    <td>{{vehicle.location}}</td>
</tr>
```

`vehicles$` is an `observable<Vehicle[]>` and the data is displayed correctly, however, when I change the checked state for some checkboxes, the `vehicle.checked` property in the data bound observable is not changed.

What am I missing?

Here's the full component source:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';
import { ConfirmationService } from '@jaspero/ng2-confirmations';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pluck';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


import { ResolveEmit, ConfirmSettings } from '../../shared/interfaces/jaspero';
import { VehiclesService } from '../../core/services/vehicles.service';
import { Vehicle } from '../../shared/interfaces/vehicle';
import { PagedResults } from 'app/shared/interfaces/paged-results';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicles-search',
  templateUrl: './vehicles-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicles-search.component.scss'],
  providers: [VehiclesService]
})
export class VehiclesSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  vehicles$: Observable<Vehicle[]>;
  totalRecords$: Observable<number>;
  page = 1;
  searchTerm = '';

  searchTermStream = new Subject<string>();
  pageStream = new Subject<number>();

  constructor(
    private vehiclesService: VehiclesService,
    private router: Router,
    private notification: NotificationsService,
    private confirmation: ConfirmationService
  ) { }

  search(term: string) {
    this.searchTermStream.next(term);
  }

  assignAnomaly() {
    this.vehicles$
      .map(m => {
        console.log(m); return m.filter(f => f.checked);
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res.length < 1) {
          this.notification.warn('Associar Anomalia', 'Você deve selecionar um veículo antes.');
        }
      });
  }

  setPage(page: number) {
    this.pageStream.next(page);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const searchSource = this.searchTermStream
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .map(term => {
        this.searchTerm = term;
        return { search: term, page: 1 };
      });

    const pageSource = this.pageStream
      .map(pageNumber => {
        this.page = pageNumber;
        return { search: this.searchTerm, page: pageNumber };
      });

    const source = pageSource
      .merge(searchSource)
      .startWith({ search: this.searchTerm, page: this.page })
      .switchMap((params: { search: string, page: number }) => {
        return this.vehiclesService.getVehicles(params.search, params.page);
      });

      this.totalRecords$ = source.pluck('totalRecords');
      this.vehicles$ = source.pluck('results');
  }

  setChecked(val, ev) {
    console.log(val);
    console.log(ev);
  }
}
```

Http service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

import { PagedResults } from '../../shared/interfaces/paged-results';
import { Vehicle } from '../../shared/interfaces/vehicle';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Injectable()
export class VehiclesService {

  private baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/vehicles`;  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getVehicles(filter: string, page: number): Observable<PagedResults<Vehicle[]>> {
    filter = filter ? `/${filter}` : '';
    return this.http
      .get<Vehicle[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/page/${page}${filter}`, {observe: 'response'})
      .map((res) => {
        const totalRecords = +res.headers.get('X-InlineCount');
        const results = res.body;

        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          results[i].checked = false;
        }

        return {
          results: res.body,
          totalRecords: totalRecords
        };
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getVehicleById(id: number): Observable<Vehicle> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it isn't changing? of course it is, in the ngFor scope, not anywhere else.  As is the intended behavior.  You need to capture the event in code and push that back through the source.

Comment: But how do I do this? With other variables, if I use `[(ngModel)]="varName", it gets updated in my class. How do I do the same for this observable?

Comment: so where did you get `vehicles$`? are you able to process it in the onChange code? something like: `(change)="vehicle.checked =!vehicle.checked; vehicles$ = Observable.of(xxxxx)"`

Comment: `vehicle$` is set using the http service, but using a `Subject<>` to provide realtime filtering and server side pagination. I'm adding the complete source to the question.

Comment: Any thougts? I tried changing the input to `<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle-selection" id="vehicle-{{vehicle.id}}" value="{{vehicle.id}}" [ngModel]="vehicle.checked" (ngModelChange)="setChecked(vehicle.id, $event)" />` and from the `setChecked` method I'm able to get the new state, but I don't know how to find the respective item in the observable array and set its checked property accordingly.

Comment: you can add the index of the vehicle to the function. `<tr *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles$; let index = index">` and then `setChecked(vehicle.id, $event, index)` and map/filter your observable to the index

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an `Array` of `Vehicle` instead of the `Observable`, you start it empty, then subscribe to `getVehicles`, and add them to the array or replace them.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `[(ngModel)]="vehicle.checked"` in the check box binding.

`[ngModel]="vehicle.checked"` is just one-way binding, it will  just change the ui when the vehicle's checked property changed.

if you want the checkbox affect the checked property, you should used two-way binding , which is `[(ngModel)]="vehicle.checked"` .

Comment: Already tried that, but as another user pointed, the change stays in the ngFor scope, thus my model variable isn't updated.